# Angular 2/4 keypress with Firefox

Tags: angular, firefox, keypress

I'm using Angular 4 with Firefox 57 and I have the following input field:

```
<input mdbActive type="tel" id="phoneNumber" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="userdetail.phoneNumber" required (keypress)="restrictNumberInput($event)" (paste)="false">
```

The backend code is:

```
restrictNumberInput(event: any) {
    let regexStr = '^[0-9]+$';
    let e = <KeyboardEvent>event;
    if ([8, 9, 27, 13, 190].indexOf(e.keyCode) !== -1 ||
        // Allow: Ctrl+A
        (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
        // Allow: Ctrl+C
        (e.keyCode == 67 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
        // Allow: Ctrl+V
        (e.keyCode == 86 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
        // Allow: Ctrl+X
        (e.keyCode == 88 && e.ctrlKey === true)) {// ||
        // Allow: home, end, left, right
        //(e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)) {
        // let it happen, don't do anything
        return;
    }

    let ch = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
    let regEx = new RegExp(regexStr);
    if (regEx.test(ch))
        return;
    else
        e.preventDefault();
}
```

I've added a breakpoint on the first line of this code and it doesnt stop.

The restrictNumberInput function doesn't run when I press any key. Why would this be?

Comment: can you please also post your back end code which fail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by breaking binding in two pieces as below :

```
<input mdbActive type="tel" id="phoneNumber" class="form-control" [ngModel]="userdetail.phoneNumber" required (ngModelChange)="restrictNumberInput($event)" (paste)="false"/> {{userdetail.phoneNumber}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is now `(keyup)` in Angular 2+.

> The (keyup) event handler hears every keystroke.

See the User Input guide on Angular's website for more information: 
https://angular.io/guide/user-input#key-event-filtering-with-keyenter

---

#### Fixing your HTML snippet

Simply changing `(keypress)` to `(keyup)` will fix your provided example.

```html
<input mdbActive type="tel" id="phoneNumber" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="userdetail.phoneNumber" required (keyup)="restrictNumberInput($event)" (paste)="false">
```

Comment: That does allow me to enter values in the field, however, this then allows for any values to be entered. The idea here is to intercept the keystrokes and only allow numbers

Comment: Simply return true if you allow the input (for numerical values only, in your case), and false when you don't. See the answer by @Ankit Kapoor for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `keyup` event for listening to keyboard Events.
Plus in your restrictNumberInput method you need to return true/false on the basis of restricition.

```
restrictNumberInput(event: KeyboardEvent) {
   if(condition_to_allow_numbers) {
      return true; // This will allow user input to be entered
    } else {
      return false; // This won't allow user input to be entered.
    }
}
```